# Get a value from a dictionary in flask function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I'm trying to make a request to a flask function and get the correct response using javascript. The user inputs something in a search field and the script should make a request with the input value and load the response data. But after adding this code, autocomplete stops working. What I got in JS/html:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item.value);
    $.getJSON("{{url_for('test')}}", val: ui.item.value, function(data) {
      $('#test').text(data);
    });
}
<div id="test"></div>
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    word = request.args.get('val')
    d = {"John": "a", "Bill": "b"}
    output = d[word]
    return jsonify(data=output)
```

For example if user inputs John, the script should load "a". Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("{{url_for('test')}}", val: ui.item.value, function(data) {
  $('#test').text(data);
});
```

Two notes:

1. The data argument to `$.getJSON` should be an object: `{val: ui.item.value}`. The bare colon `:` is invalid.
2. The success callback receives a JSON-decoded object that you're calling `data`. But this is just an object; the field you want is inside the object and is also called `data`.

This should work:

```
$.getJSON("{{url_for('test')}}", {val: ui.item.value}, function(data) {
  $('#test').text(data.data);
});
```